# Make icons appear as circles

Tags: html, icons

Hi guys I want to change the look of these icons to a circle version.

Here's the current code:

```
<span>
    <a href="/futbol" rel="noopener"><img style="border-radius: 50%" src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/MX-flag.webp" alt="Mexico Flag Translation" width="50"></a>
</span> <span style="color:white">SP</span> <span style="color:white">|</span>
<span>
    <a href="/" rel="noopener"><img style="border-radius: 50%" src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/US-flag.jpeg" alt="English Flag Translation" width="50"></a>
</span> <span style="color:white">EN</span>
```

I tried doing it myself but couldn't make it.

Now they appear like ovals, what should I add to the code for the images to show as circles?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS tag `border-radius: 50%` for your img tag.

You can do this in html with:

```
<img style="border-radius: 50%" src...
```

Or do it in a CSS file with:

```
img { border-radius: 50%; }
```

If your images are not squared use this in html (example is with 50px, but you can use whatever you need):

```
<img style="width: 50px; height: 50px; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 50%;" src=...
```

or this in a CSS file:

```
img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

With this code you are forcing the image to use the same width and height, which makes it squared. After that we are using the `object-fit: cover` CSS tag, which will stop the image from stretching. Without this tag the image will stretch and distort, because you are forcing a new aspect ratio.

Comment: Great man! Thanks a lot!

How can I keep changing them to look more like a circle instead of an oval?

Comment: Your Image isn‘t a square. In the CSS you can set the width and height to the Same and then use the object-fit Tag and set it to Cover. I will edit this comment with an example as soon as I open my Laptop.

Comment: Here is the example:

`img { width: 50px; height: 50px; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 50%; }`

or in inline css:

`<img style="width: 50px; height: 50px; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 50%;" src=...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to the image add `border-radius: 50%;` using css.
Like in CSS/Style tag

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use css property border-radius as:

```
    img {
          border-radius: 50%; 
        }
```

or if you want inline css :

```
style="border-radius: 50%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your image not square.

Try to Add width and height to the same value.

Your img width is 50px, so try add 50px height in img.

This link is related to image style : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

```
<span>
    <a href="/futbol" rel="noopener"><img style="border-radius: 50%" src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/MX-flag.webp" alt="Mexico Flag Translation" width="50" height="50"></a>
</span> <span style="color:white">SP</span> <span style="color:white">|</span>
<span>
    <a href="/" rel="noopener"><img style="border-radius: 50%" src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/US-flag.jpeg" alt="English Flag Translation" width="50" height="50"></a>
</span> <span style="color:white">EN</span>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).